# Input in textboxes containing html tags trigger HttpRequestValidationException when radio buttons are changed

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a page with multiple radio buttons that show different search panels containing distinct textboxes and search buttons. I am currently using javascript to prevent textboxes containing html tags from being sent to the server when the search button is clicked. As I am continuing testing, I noticed that if there are html tags in a text box, a different radio button is clicked, the form is automatically submitted, or at least triggers the dangerous input exception. I'm not sure how the application is detecting the input just when the textbox changes. If the textbox contains normal text and the radio button changes, no postback occurs.

Answer (score 0):

May be your script getting failed and not validating due to error and not preventing postback as it is not executing  properly due to error..